# What does Groot say to Captain America?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, avengers-infinity-war

When Thor introduced Groot to Captain America, the reply from Groot was "I am Groot" .. what is he saying in his language here?

Comment: Is it possible that he was merely saying, "My name is Groot"?

Comment: @JohnnyBones .... I took it to be exactly that joke ... that at this moment, English and Groot language said the same thing.  However there's no way to tell for sure.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Noo...you mean "I am Groot" means "I am Groot"?

Comment: Shoot a question to @JamesGunn on Twitter, he might answer. He answered a fan question that Groot says "Dad" as his last words before disintegration referring to Rocket

Comment: I could answer that question but I am afraid someone will shout "Language!" if I do

Comment: **Thor - By the way, this is a friend of mine, Tree.** I guess Groot is saying that he is not Tree because he is not tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groot

Answer (score 11):

## We don't know...

...but it's *likely* he's saying exactly what he actually means.

> Oh, by the way, this is a friend of mine. A tree.
>
> I am Groot!
>
> I am Steve Rogers.

The joke here is that **everything** Groot ever says in his language comes out as "I am Groot"...it's just that in this specific instance the sounds match what he *would* say in these circumstances.

Comment: But his name isn't Groot. Groot, as mentioned by Thor, is a (elective)language.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. "Elective" just means it's a subject you *can* take not one you are *required* to take.

Comment: It was *tongue-in-cheek*. Hilarious when Thor delivered it. Ignore

Comment: Agreed....and you aren't wrong, it's possible Groot isn't his name...he could have been saying "Hello". :)

Comment: I am not sure about this answer. To me, the joke in that scene is that Steve Rogers took literally what Groot said. Groot could have said anything from "Were is Starbucks?", "There is no Wifi" to "I am Groot".